# C# coding guideline of how to use AsParallel() / Parellel.ForEach()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing

I want to calculate Jaccard similarity on 10 000 texts. 
Jaccard Similarity is easy to calculate : length of the intersect divided by the length of the union.

```
string sTtxt1 = "some text one";
string sTtxt2 = "some text two";
string sTtxt3 = "some text three";
HashSet<string[]> hashText= new HashSet<string[]>();
hashText.Add(sTtxt1);
hashText.Add(sTtxt2);
hashText.Add(sTtxt3);
double[,] dSimilarityValue;

for (int i = 0; i < hashText.Count; i++)
{
   dSimilarityValue[i, i] = 100.00;
   for (int j = i + 1; j < dSimilarityValue.Count; j++)
   {
      dSimilarityValue[i, j] = (double) hashText.ElementAt(i).Intersect(hashText.ElementAt(j)).Count() / (double) hashText.ElementAt(i).Union(hashText.ElementAt(j)).Count();
   }
}
```

With .NET4, What rules should I use to parallelizing ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the inner loop parallel for

[Parallel Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd989744.aspx)

```
Parallel.For(0, N, i =>
{
   // Do Work.
}); 


Parallel.For(j, dSimilarityValue.Count, i =>
{
   dSimilarityValue[i, j] = 
    (double)hashText.ElementAt(i).Intersect(hashText.ElementAt(j)).Count() / 
    (double)hashText.ElementAt(i).Union(hashText.ElementAt(j)).Count();
});
```

And I think it would be better to declare the size of the Array in new.
Don't know what you mean by "rules".

Comment: Blam, by "rules" I wanted to say "method" (Excuse me for my poor English I'm French ;)) 
It's good with Parallel.For(). I reduced the processing time by 10. Thank's four your help.

I tested 
`(double)hashText.AsParallel().ElementAt(i).Intersect(hashText.ElementAt(j)).Count() / (double)hashText.AsParallel().ElementAt(i).Union(hashText.ElementAt(j)).Count();`
but performance is degraded

Comment: The ElementAt() is singular so it cannot spin up multiple threads.  That inner loop is a logical point for the parallel.

Comment: So use another data structure that `HashSet <string[]>` to parallelize Intersect() & Union(). But which one?

Comment: HashSet is good.  As I said the inner loop is the logical point for the parallel.